# sHow to convert SimpleCursorAdapter to ListAdapter to suit a library?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-listview

I am trying to use this library to do listview sliding woth the data getting from database.

https://github.com/47deg/android-swipelistview/blob/master/README.md#download

However, according to the library, it needs data type called ListAdapter

```
@Override
public void setAdapter(ListAdapter adapter) {
    super.setAdapter(adapter);
    touchListener.resetItems();
    adapter.registerDataSetObserver(new DataSetObserver() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged() {
            super.onChanged();
            onListChanged();
            touchListener.resetItems();
        }
    });
}
```

But I am using SimpleCursorAdapter to get data from the SQLite and I want to setAdapter to this library listview. I don't know what is the difference of setting adapter as usual.

Could anyone give me some ideas about how to do it?
I am very frustrated using this library, thank you very much!

Comment: SimpleCursorAdapter implements ListAdapter

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. Do you mean use a new class to implement ListAdapter and put the new class as an arguement? i.e. listview.setAdapter( class SimpleCursorAdapter implements ListAdapter)? can you give me a sample?

Comment: no, you. can use SCA as SCA iextends BaseAdapter wich in turn mplements ListAdapter